# Best way to implement multiple hash tables in C?

Tags: c, hashtable

Hej everyone.
I currently need to implement 3 diffrent kind of Hash Tables in C.
I try to come up with a idea how to initalize thes in a way without coding a "create","set","get" .. etc. function for every table I need.

The tables would look like

```
typedef struct ht_can_t {
    uint32_t key;
    list_variable *variables;
    struct ht_can_t *next;
} ht_can_t;

typedef struct ht_iena_t {
    uint32_t key;
    list_variable *variables;
    struct ht_iena_t *next;
} ht_iena_t;

typedef struct ht_variable_t {
    char *key;
    uint8_t length;
    uint8_t *data;
    struct ht_variable_t *next;
} ht_variable_t;

typedef struct {
    ht_can_t **entry;
} ht_can;

typedef struct {
    ht_iena_t **entry;
} ht_iena;

typedef struct {
    ht_variable_t **entry;
} ht_variable;
```

I would only write these tables once during initialization and then only read information doing runtime.

All function i got at the time to create, write to, add to this tables would bust this question, thus following is only the CAN part.

```
ht_can *ht_create_can(void) {
    // Alloc space for entry
    ht_can *ht = malloc(sizeof(ht_can));
    // Alloc space for TABLE_SIZE times CAN Hashtable
    ht->entry = malloc(sizeof(ht_can_t*) * TABLE_SIZE);
    // Write NULL to every entry
    for (int i=0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i) {
        ht->entry[i] = NULL;
    }
    
    return ht;
}

ht_can_t *ht_add_can(uint32_t key, list_variable* var) {
    // Alloc space for Hashtable
    ht_can_t *entry = malloc(sizeof(ht_can_t));
    // Write Key
    entry->key = key;
    // Write variable list
    entry->variables = var;
    // Write next as NULL
    entry->next = NULL;
    
    return entry;
}

void ht_set_can(ht_can *ht, uint32_t key, list_variable* var) {
    // Get Hash value
    int slot = hash_int(key);
    // Access entry with Hash
    ht_can_t *entry = ht->entry[slot];
    // Write to if empty
    if (entry == NULL) {
        ht->entry[slot] = ht_add_can(key, var);
        return;
    }
    // Search for machtching Key
    while (entry != NULL) {
        if (entry->key == key) {
            entry->variables = var;
            return;
        }
        entry = entry->next;
    }
    // if no matching key found, add to end of hashtable
    entry->next = ht_add_can(key, var);
}

list_variable* ht_get_can(ht_can *ht, uint32_t key) {
    // Get Hash value
    int slot = hash_int(key);
    // Access entry with Hash
    ht_can_t *entry = ht->entry[slot];
    // Return if not exist
    if (entry == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // Search for matching key
    while (entry != NULL) {
        if (entry->key == key) {
            // Return variable List
            return entry->variables;
        }
        entry = entry->next;
    }
    // Return if no matching Key exist
    return NULL;
}
```

Do I have to write that again for every other Table?
Or is there a diffrent way?

Comment: Sounds like the best way would be to use C++ instead

Comment: I could, but that would probably ruin my work for 2 months xD. I'm working on the STM32H7 with the SW4STM32. Unfortunately this has been optimized for C and I would get more problems elsewhere ^^'

Comment: If you somehow find a solution, I'm pretty sure it won't make things any easier. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I try to come up with a idea how to initalize thes in a way without coding a "create","set","get" .. etc. function for every table I need.

There are basically limited realistic possible ways to implement *templates* in C.

1. Using preprocessor,

   - Using a single big fat macro. Do not reinventing the wheel - for lists the [queue.h](https://man.openbsd.org/queue.3) is usually available, newlib also has it. If not, it's just a header to copy. I remember also seeing a header for hash tables - for sure there are many implementations on gihtub.

```
#define DECL_HASH(N, T)  \
\
typedef struct {\
    ht_##N##_t **entry;\
} ht_##N;\
\
typedef struct ht_##N##_t { \
    uint32_t key; \
    T *variables; \
    struct ht_##N##_t *next; \
} ht##N##_t; \
\
ht_##N *ht_create_##N(void) { \
    ht_##N *ht = malloc(sizeof(*ht)); \
    ht->entry = malloc(sizeof(ht##N##_t*) * TABLE_SIZE); \
    for (int i=0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i) { \
        ht->entry[i] = NULL; \
    }     \
    return ht; \
} \
\
/* etc. for each function to do */

DECL_HASH(can, list_variables)
struct iena_data_s { list_variables variables; };
DECL_HASH(iena, struct iena_data_s)
 //etc.
```

- Using a header file that you set some parameters and include. Many projects do it in different cases - like [glibc strfrom*.c files](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/strfroml.c#L40).

```
// hash.t.h
// handy macros for concatenation
#define _c_(a, b) a##b
#define _c(a, b) _c_(a, b)
#define _c3_(a, b, c) a##b##c
#define _c3(a, b, c) _c3_(a, b, c)

// use preprocssor so that you do not have to type ( ) so much
#define ht_name_t  _c3(ht_, NAME, _t)
#define ht_name    _c(ht_, NAME)
typedef struct {
    ht_name_t **entry;
} ht_name;

typedef struct ht_name_t { \
    uint32_t key;
    TYPE *variables;
    struct ht_name_t *next;
} ht_name_t;

#define ht_create_name  _c(ht_create_, NAME)
ht_name *ht_create_name(void) {
    ht_name *ht = malloc(sizeof(*ht));
    ht->entry = malloc(sizeof(ht##N##_t*) * TABLE_SIZE);
    for (int i=0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i) {
        ht->entry[i] = NULL;
    }
    return ht;
}

#define ht_add_name  _c(ht_add_, NAME)
ht_name_t *ht_add_name(uint32_t key, list_variable* var) {
   ...
}

/* etc. for each function */

// pick up the trash
#undef ht_add_name
#undef ht_create_name
#undef ht_name
#undef ht_name_t
#undef _c3
#undef _c3_
#undef _c_
#undef _c
#undef NAME

// hash_can.c
#define NAME can
struct can_type_s { list_variables *variables; };
#define TYPE struct can_type_s
#include "hash.t.h"

// hash_iena.c
#define NAME iena
struct can_iena_s { list_variables *variables; };
#define TYPE struct can_iena_s
#include "hash.t.h"
```

2. Using virtual functions that implement all operations and a dispatch table. Ie. [g_hash_table](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) as an example from glib and maybe all of linux kernel, like `file_operations` structure for example. This is the recommended way you would *want* to implement, it's easy to unit test, it's easy to maintain and kind of forces you to write nice code. A *very* very crude example in pseudocode that I am way too bored to implement fully:

```
// hash.c
typedef void *hash_elem;
struct hash_elem_vtable_s {
    // add all functions that you will need, no idea which
    int (*init)(hash_elem**); // constructor
    int (*copy)(hash_elem* to, const hash_elem*from); // assignemnt
    int (*move)(hash_elem** to, const hash_elem*from); // move constructor
    int (*destroy)(hash_elem*); // destructor
}; 
struct hash_s {
    void *elem;
    const struct hash_elem_vtable_s *ev;
    struct hash_s *next;
};
int hash_add(hash_s *t, hash_elem *elem_to_add) {
    ...
    int r = t->ev->move(&t->elem, elem_to_add);
    if (!r) return -ERROR_NUMBER;
    ...
}


// then instantiate hash_s for each element type.
```

3. Using code generation.

Comment: Thx :D Thats some input I can work with! It's probally will safe me some time (Also considered on future projects)

Answer (score 0):

KamilCuk gave a good answer. But if you find the preprocessor daunting, an alternative approach is to use whatever scripting language you like, and simply write a script that generates the source files.

A drawback is that it can complicate the build process, but a benefit is that Python and similar languages is way easier to read than C macros.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should have to store in the structure the elements necessary to maintain your table.  You need a comparison function to compare two entries for equality to be able to detect collissions, you need a function to calculate the hash value from the key, and a function to allocate a copy (if necessary) of the key (and/or also for the data element) of the entry, in case you will store references only or a full copy of the object.  You should pass pointers  to these functions when constructing the hash table, and they should be used internally to manage the entries.  Then with just one implementation, you can handle all those kinds of hash tables.